# Invalid URL exception when calling endpoint with port in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm working on a large .NET Core project where we have the need to make REST requests from C# to specific server endpoints.

The endpoints are specified in the format `http://some.domain.com:70`.

When called, an exception of type `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` is thrown, with the message `The URL is invalid`.

When calling endpoints that omit the port in the address, it works fine.
It also works fine when running it in .NET Framework 4.6 instead of .NET Core.

Since almost all 3rd party libraries that could simplify these outgoing calls relies on `System.Net.Http`, the problem remains.

Below is a minimum working example that can be tried as a console application (exception thrown in .NET Core, works fine in .NET Framework 4.6)

```
using System;

    namespace NetCoreConsoleTestREST
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Calling service...");
                Test();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }


            public static async void Test()
            {
                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
                var res = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://some.domain.com:70")); //This doesn't work in .NET Core
                //var res = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://requestb.in/wy9h8gwy")); //This works perfectly fine

                Console.WriteLine(res);
            }
        }
    }
```

The .NET Core versions I have installed

```
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86
```

Is this a bug in .NET CoreFX or by design?

---

**Update**
It will only fail if I use the port number 70. If I switch to i.e 1234 it works.

Comment: I don't get that exception message in .Net Core. which version are you using?

Comment: Fails on .Net Core Version 1.1.0

Comment: I don't get that message either. Please give us the dependencies that you have on your project i am using .Net Core 1.1.0 too with System.Net.Http 4.3.2. Try to request the same url from your browser. You may have forgotten to add something.

Comment: You may have some odd characters in your URL too. Could you provide some actual code that shows the error occurring as the snippet above is fine (other than the fact you're not waiting on the async `Test` method)

Comment: The URL is written and not pasted, so no hidden invalid characters or similar. The above code is a simplified example that actually does throw the error for me when running it in VS2017 as a .NET Core Console Application. I've updated the question with exact versions of the runtime.

Comment: Just noticed that it will only fail with port 70, not 1234. And that should be the answer; port 70 is according to the RFC1700 reserved for the VISA protocol, and thus not usable in this case. I'll switch ports and this should work!

Comment: If you're using custom ports for HTTP, then you should go with high numbers to be sure you're not conflicting. However, even using 70 in my environment, I still don't get that error.

Comment: Strange that it's not reproducible on your side. I get the error with any bogus endpoint URL as long as I use  the port 70. I've notified those responsible for the service to change ports to something in the available range. Seems like a silly mistake but nonetheless an easy one to make.

Comment: Can you post the code that actually fails for you? (You say it only fails on port 70, but the code is question has 1234.)

Comment: @svick It actually fails with http://some.domain.com:70 with the exception thrown. I think it's just updated in. NET Core to block ports that are reserved. Using a port in the higher range solved it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is specifically caused by using port 70. `HttpClient` on .Net Core on Windows uses WinHTTP. And [What's New in WinHTTP 5.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384086(v=vs.85).aspx) says (emphasis mine):

> Starting with Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP with SP2, **sending requests to the following well-known, non-HTTP, ports is restricted** for security reasons: 21 (FTP), 25 (SMTP), **70 (GOPHER)**, 110 (POP3), 119 (NNTP), 143 (IMAP).

Comment: Nice find! IIRC, I tried other reserved ports that didn't work that aren't mentioned in the article you link. I'll recheck asap tomorrow and get back on that, otherwise I consider this to be the answer!